# Approriate way of returning several lists in python function

Tags: python, list, function, error-handling

I have a function:

```
def extract_embedding_word2vec(y_text, w_e):
    
    n_run = len(y_text)    
    y_e = []
    false_index = []
    sentence_index = []
    
    for i in range(n_run):
        word2vec_run = []
        false_index_this_run = []
        sentence_index_this_run = []
        for j in range(len(y_text[i])):    
            if(len(y_text[i][j]) == 1):
                sentence_index_this_run.append(1)
                try:
                    word2vec_run.append(word2vec_model.wv[y_text[i][j][0].lower()])
                    false_index_this_run.append(1)
                except:
                    word2vec_run.append(word2vec_model.wv["lol"]) #fixme, until here
                    #print(y_text[i][j])
                    not_included_words.add(y_text[i][j][0].lower())
                    false_index_this_run.append(0)
                    #print("not included: %s" %y_text[i][j])
            else:
                sentence_index_this_run.append(0)
                
            
        
        y_e.append(word2vec_run)
        false_index.append(false_index_this_run)
        sentence_index.append(sentence_index_this_run)
    
    
    # Output format: list of n_run ta, each element: n_stim * n_dim_of_embedding

    print(len(y_e[0][0]))
    return (y_e, false_index, sentence_index)
```

Also:

```
def join_list(list2d):
    
    new_list = []
    
    for i in range(len(list2d)):
        for j in range(len(list2d[i])):
            new_list.append(list2d[i][j])
            
    return (new_list)
```

Then, later, I call this function like this:

```
y_e, false_index, sentence_index = extract_embedding_word2vec(y_t, w_e)
y_joined = join_list(y_sep)
f_joined = join_list[flag_sep]
s_joined = join_list[sen_sep]
```

It works well for "y_joined", but for f_joined I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

In some other threads I found that this error might be due to if we had defined for example the "flag_sep" as a function somewhere... but I searched in my codes and realized there was no new definition/use of this variable.

Is there something about appropriate way of returning several python lists in a function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use a python debugger such as visual studio code to view the returned values and check for potential cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo with bracket types. You need `()` not `[]`. `[]` is used for indexing over iterables.

Try this while calling:

```
f_joined = join_list(flag_sep)
s_joined = join_list(sen_sep)
```

Comment: Oh, it was such a mistake and I didn't realize it. It is working now. Thank you very much.
(I can put the "accepted mark" in 5 minutes)